# SharePoint Online Form Processing

Tags: javascript, html, forms, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I wrote a simple HTML/PHP form that takes input from a form and outputs to HTML to create a company standard email signature. It just echoes the strings from the form fields into the HTML for the signature.

Form:

```
<form action="sig.php" method="post">
Full Name: <input type="text" name="fullName"><br>
Job Title: <input type="text" name="jobTitle"><br>
Direct Phone Number (xxx.xxx.xxxx) <input type="text" name="phoneNumber"><br>
Email: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

PHP:

```
<div style="font-size:10pt; font-family:'Arial',sans-serif;color:#0E5881">
Please copy/paste the following into your email signature:
</div>
<hr>
<br>
<br>
<div style="font-size:12pt; font-family:'Arial',sans-serif;color:#133467">
<b><?php echo $_POST["fullName"]; ?></b>
</div>
<div style="font-size:10pt; font-family:'Arial',sans-serif;color:#0E5881">
<?php echo $_POST["jobTitle"]; ?>
</div>
<div style="font-size:10pt; font-family:'Arial',sans-serif;color:#656565">
Direct:</b>&nbsp;<?php echo $_POST["phoneNumber"]; ?>
<br>
<a href="mailto:<?php echo $_POST["email"]; ?>"><?php echo $_POST["email"]; ?></a>&nbsp;&#124;&nbsp;<a href="http://www.example.com">www.Example.com</a>
</div>
<br>
<div style="font-size:20pt; font-family:'Arial',sans-serif;color:#676767">
<b>Example.com</b>
```

It works great, but now they tell me they want to put it on our company's SharePoint Online site.

As far as I can tell, there is no way to run the PHP on SharePoint. I also can't use a PageViewer Web Part.

What is my best option for doing this through SharePoint? Something client side that will run inside of SharePoint? I think Java Script is an option, but I don't know anything about it. I know SharePoint uses ASP, but I know even less about that.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What is your goal? You can use standart list and create custom form or use web-part...

Comment: My goal is to have the same functionality as I do in the above script on SharePoint. I looked into using the page viewer web part, but I don't have access to any external hosting for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP is server-side code, which you cannot add in SharePoint online unless you're willing to write your own SharePoint apps.

For something like this, your best bet is probably just a page with some JavaScript.

```js
document.getElementById("btnSubmit").addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.getElementById("signaturePanel").style.display = "inherit";
  document.getElementById("fullNameOut").innerHTML = document.getElementById("fullName").value;
  document.getElementById("jobTitleOut").innerHTML = document.getElementById("jobTitle").value;
  document.getElementById("phoneNumberOut").innerHTML = document.getElementById("phoneNumber").value;
  var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
  var emailOut = document.getElementById("emailOut");
  emailOut.innerHTML = email;
  emailOut.href = "mailto:" + email;
  document.getElementById("socialOut").style.display = document.getElementById("social").checked ? "inherit" : "none";
  
});
```

```html
Full Name:
<input type="text" id="fullName" />
<br>Job Title:
<input type="text" id="jobTitle" />
<br>Direct Phone Number (xxx.xxx.xxxx)
<input type="text" id="phoneNumber" />
<br>Email:
<input type="text" id="email" />
<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="social" checked="checked" />Include social media links
<br/>
<input type="button" id="btnSubmit" value="submit" />

<div id="signaturePanel" style="display:none">
  <div style="font-size:10pt; font-family:'Arial',sans-serif;color:#0E5881;">
    Please copy/paste the following into your email signature:
  </div>
  <hr>
  <br>
  <br>
  <div style="font-size:12pt; font-family:'Arial',sans-serif;color:#133467">
    <b><span id="fullNameOut"></span></b>
  </div>
  <div style="font-size:10pt; font-family:'Arial',sans-serif;color:#0E5881">
    <span id="jobTitleOut"></span>
  </div>
  <div style="font-size:10pt; font-family:'Arial',sans-serif;color:#656565">
    Direct:</b>&nbsp;<span id="phoneNumberOut"></span>
    <br>
    <a id="emailOut" href="mailto:"></a>&nbsp;&#124;&nbsp;<a href="http://www.example.com">www.Example.com</a>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div style="font-size:20pt; font-family:'Arial',sans-serif;color:#676767">
    <b>Example.com</b>
    <div id="socialOut" style="display:none">
      <a href="http://example.com">
        <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=15&txt=twitter+link&w=90&h=90&txttrack=0" />
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: This seems to do exactly what I want. What's my best bet on implementing it? Put the javascript into script tags?

Comment: I got this to run and it is doing nearly everything I need. However, the part that is supposed to create the mailto link isn't working. It outputs the email address, but the link is just a mailto: that doesn't contain the email address.

Comment: That did it. I put the script at the bottom of the page in script tags and added it to the code of a SharePoint page and it is working perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: Hey, sorry to dig this one back up. Do you know of a way to add a checkbox, that if checked would add additional HTML to the generated signature? Some people add img links to our social media pages. So the extra code would just add some <img> and <a href> tags to the end.

Comment: Sure thing. I added some code to the example above for showing the contents of a div when a corresponding checkbox has been checked.

Comment: You are an amazing individual.

Comment: I wanted to add a note for anyone who might come across this: I found that when I ran this inside Sharepoint it would run and then refresh the page. After much searching, I found that it worked properly when I changed the button from `type="submit"` to `type="button"` As I understand it, submit posts the form content, which looks like a refresh.